# Periodic index of several datasources by Apache Solr and update of subset of fields without document renewal

Tags: apache, solr, dataimporthandler, data-importer

I have following situation:

2 datasources should be indexed by Apache Solr.

1. RDBM - constantly available
2. CSV file which can be pushed to the system from time to time.

CSV file just update 2 fields on already existing documents in Solr.

But I have following problem: it seems impossible to make update just some subset of fields by DataImportHandler. Is it really impossible or there is some trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem lies in trying to "update" an existing document with only two fields.
Which version of Solr are you using? Partial updates are only supported for Solr 4.x.

Here's some information on what partial updates are and how to do them:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates

http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/

Comment: I use 4.6.0. Update through json works ok, but bulk update by DataImportHandler just rewrite existings docs.

Comment: Ah, DIH does not support partial updates sadly. I think there is an open jira ticket to add this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327473/dataimporthandler-and-partial-updates